# Botão voltar na webview

Tags: android, webview

Estou começando na área de desenvolvimento de aplicativos android. Sendo assim comecei a desenvolver um aplicativo o qual criei 4 layouts ( Tela principal, central do assinante, contato e planos). No activity central do assinante coloquei uma webview e quando o cliente aperta o botão voltar do celular consegue navegar pelas páginas com esse código que coloquei no java da activity:

```
Override
public void onBackPressed(){

if (mywebView.canGoBack()){

mywebView.goBack();

} else {

}
```

Só que quando o cliente navega dentro da webview e volta na página principal da web através do botão do celular, para nessa página e não volta para o menu.

Tentei criar um botão voltar com startactivity no cabeçalho para retornar ao menu, mas dá erro dizendo "o aplicativo parou".

Agradeço desde já pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Se você não estiver finalizando a atividade principal ao iniciar a atividade da central do assinante, você pode simplesmente encerrar esta segunda atividade para voltar para a primeira.

Exemplo:

```
Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if (mywebView.canGoBack()){
        mywebView.goBack();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigada. Funcionou!

Comment: Se não for abusar! Gostaria de colocar um botão no cabeçalho para o menu principal. Declarei as startactivity no main.java e chamei no botão dentro da activity com android:onclick:"startactivity". Está dando erro. Tem outra forma de fazê-lo?